# Как правильно вытащить данные из бд что бы проверить пустая ли ячейка или же нет?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Не ругайте строго. У меня такая проблема из бд mysql вытаскиваю ячейку с определенным id. Вот так.

```
      public ArrayList checkOnFilling(string id)
    {
        ArrayList checkFiling = new ArrayList();
        using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                string CommandText =String.Format("SELECT id_voprosGos FROM students where id = {0} ", Convert.ToInt32(id));
                MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
                MySqlDataReader MyDataReader;
                MyDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (MyDataReader.HasRows)
                    foreach (DbDataRecord result in MyDataReader)
                        checkFiling.Add(result);
                MyDataReader.Close();
                return checkFiling;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Проверку выполняю следующим образом

```
   private void FormFolder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Text = Program.namePath;
        dl.createFolserStudent(Program.namePath);
        ArrayList checkOnFilling = dl.checkOnFilling(Program.id);
        if(checkOnFilling == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("У студента + " + Program.namePath + " не создан первый прокол ");
            radioButton2.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {   MessageBox.Show("У студента + " + Program.namePath + "  уже создан первый потакол ");
            radioButton2.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
```

Но мой запрос все равно возвращает одну запись вне зависимости пустая ячейка или же нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы перечитайте свой вопрос. В первом блоке кода идет наполнение списка студентов `allStudent`, причем с проверкой на `MyDataReader.HasRows`, т.е. без наличия данных список останется пустым. Но вот во втором блоке ничего не понятно, что такое `dl.checkOnFilling(Program.id);`? Предлагаете ванговать?

Comment: я передаю id  - он же попадает в запрос к базе данных

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю @Bulson.

Comment: dl - это объект класса , а что после точки идет это так метод называется с запросом.

Comment: Какого класса и какого запроса?

Comment: Дополнил код! ТЕперь видно?

Comment: Это прелестно, но пока видно, что некий `dl` имеет два метода: createFolserStudent() и checkOnFilling(), но что такое dl нифига не понятно.

Comment: Dl - это объект класса DAl -где находится метод с реализацией запроса

Comment: Тогда в методе checkOnFilling() поставьте точку останова и пройдите пошагам метод, смотря значения локальных переменных, там и будет зарыта собака.

Comment: Да, и вы раньше на Java писали что ли? ArrayList в C# это древнейший отстой, им уже как сто лет в обед никто не пользуется.

Comment: Я проходил , данный метод возвращает всегда строчку даже пустую. А вопрос в том что бы помогли понять как проверить на то приходит в ответе - если пустая то вывести сообщение.

Comment: У `ArrayList` есть свойство `Count`, которое дает количество элементов в коллекции. Копайте в этом направлении.

Comment: Я про это и писал что он мне в любом случае будь там пусто или нет возвращает одну запись. т.е Count = 1

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52865/discussion-between---and-bulson).

Comment: Для этого и существуют точки остановки; ставите, смотрите значения переменных, наведите курсор на переменную, кот. отдает метод и посмотрите значение.

Comment: Извините, пока не вижу причин для чата.

Comment: Добавил картинку где при выборе пустой ячейки возвращает это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(MyDataReader["id_voprosGos"] == System.DBNull.Value)
```

Ребята с чата подсказали что нужно думать в сторону `DbNull`.
Решение выше!
Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я предпочитаю для работы с БД micro-orm. Например Peta-Poco.

Таким макаром ты можешь и в достаточной мере быстро работать з базами данных любых размеров,а так же работать с записями в БД как с обьектами.

то есть достать нужный обьект по айдишнику,например так:

```
var article = db.Single<Article>(123);
```

и потом уже любое поле article проверяешь на нулл. Вот и все.

Если работать с ORM вместо micro-ORM даже подобный запрос не нужно будет делать. Просто LONQовский запрос на поиск по айдишнику и точно такая же провернка нужного параметра.

ОРМки -- это очень удобно.

Советую.